# Swift How to set background color with custom color programmatically?

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to change background color of a UILabel with a custom color programmatically.

Could anyone can tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I would like to know how to use the color that is stored in *Assets.xcassets* folder.

Comment: For a color in the assets folder, just use `UIColor(named: "YourColorNameHere")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aheze wrote in the comment, I used `UIColor(named: "YourColorNameHere")`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way:

```
labelname.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

or

```
labelname.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0, green:159.0/255.0, blue:184.0/255.0)
```